# ESP32 custom board review

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, pcb-design, schematics, esp32

I have just finished the electronic design of my project and would like to request a review from anyone with more experience in PCB design. It's a custom development 2-layer board based on the ESP32-S3-MINI-1 module, but it also includes some additional features:

- An ICS-43434 MEMS microphone (*bottom ported*)
- Wire-to-wire connector housing for a battery.
- A Li-Ion, Li-Polymer single-cell battery charge management controller (MCP73831).
- In addition to the common USB connector that connects to the USB-UART bridge IC, it also has another USB connector directly linked to the built-in USB-OTG transceiver of the ESP32-S3 chip.

I am particularly concerned about my PCB design. My goal is to achieve a decent board with good EMC and also a board that addresses EMI suppression. I have made efforts to consider bypass and filter capacitors, track angles, vias, crosstalking, and the quality of ground planes. However, due to a tight deadline, it's possible that I have made mistakes or had malpractice in some cases related to any of the aforementioned items.

The link below has the PDF files for both the schematic and PCB so you can zoom in and examine them in great detail.

Link:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TwjUuETDIHZk9CK62c-Y4aYPQkmqWMDl?usp=sharing

[image: Schematic]

[image: PCB TOP]

[image: PCB BOTTOM]

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't Q1 be PMOS?

Comment: D2-D7 doesn't need to be bi-directional.

Comment: Indeed Q1 is a PMOS.  I selected the same TVS that Espressif used on his DEVKITM board, I believe that way the circuit is protected against reversed ESD voltages.